# High Speed Digital Signal Measurement

Tags: digital-logic, oscilloscope, logic-analyzer

What is the best way to measure a 40 MHz clock signal?
I tried using an oscilloscope with an 8pf passive probe, and the signal was unrecognizable. Would a logic analyzer work better in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know the bandwidth or sampling rate of the ‘scope?  If the probe is switchable, try it on x10.

Comment: Do you mean measure and/or view. What do you want to measure e.g. Amplitude, Frequency, Jitter, Modulation? What is the source and and voltage of the signal, what are you trying to achieve? For a basic measurement a logic analyzer would be overkill.

Comment: I'm using an oscilloscope with a bandwidth of 1 GHz and 5 GS/s sampling rate. The source is actually a DAC. I'm trying to measure the digital signals in a DAC such as the clock to determine parameters such as the setup/ hold time, clock jitter...etc. 
When I try measuring the clock signal, I get a signal that doesn't remotely look like a square wave. I tried using a 50-ohm terminator but that didn't help that much.

Comment: What kind of probe are you using, and how and where is its ground connected to the circuit ground?

Comment: Mostly likely your ground wire on probe was too long. Removing the clip and tip will work best on 10:1 probe

Comment: How long is the clock net? Where are you probing? Is the signal terminated? Design your PWBs so there is a clock test point with a ground at the destination. For good signal measurements, you want a 1/2" ground wire, not a 3" ground wire. If you can afford one, get a FET probe.

Answer (score 0):

There are three requirements for a 10:1 passive probe to work correctly

- The oscilloscope must be used on the 1 MΩ input
- The tip ground of the probe must be connected by a short wire to the ground on the circuit local to the clock driver
- The probe must be tuned to the oscilloscope's input capacitance

Although the resistance of a 1 MΩ scope input is well standardised, the input capacitance can vary between brands, usually in the range 15 pF to 30 pF. Most 10:1 probes have an adjustable capacitor in parallel with their internal 9 MΩ resistor, which needs to be adjusted to get a good squarewave on the scope. Many scopes include a low frequency squarewave output, usually marked 'calibrator' for this purpose.

As an alternative, you can build a very low capacitance probe to use with your scope's 50 Ω input. Use a series resistor of 500 Ω to 5 kΩ, depending on the load your driver is happy to tolerate, into a 50 Ω cable going to the 50 Ω scope input. As before, ground the business end of the 50 Ω cable to a ground local to your driver. For the resistors I've mentioned, you'll get an 11:1 to 100:1 attenuation.

Most RF and microwave engineers have several of these little probes kicking around to solder onto circuits, lose or break. They are very cheap to build, and very good performance to GHz, if you keep your connections short.

Question for bonus marks. We've all heard about matching. Why is using a 5 kΩ resistor in series with a 50 Ω line OK in this context.